# Create widgets in panel of Main Frame

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

first. I created a Panel named DataViewPanel class into  AGUIFrame class, i wanna use that Panel class in order to manage a part of GUI Frame.

**file.h**

```
 class DataViewPanel : public wxPanel
        {
        public:
            DataViewPanel(wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id = wxID_ANY, const wxPoint& pos = wxDefaultPosition, const wxSize& size = wxDefaultSize);
        };
        //DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
    };
```

**file.cpp**

```
  AGUIFrame::AGUIFrame(wxWindow* parent, int id, const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size)
        : wxFrame(parent, id, title, pos, size)
    { 
        wxPanel* dataViewPanel = new DataViewPanel(this, -1, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize);
    }

    AGUIFrame::DataViewPanel::DataViewPanel(wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size)
        : wxPanel(parent, id, pos, size)
    {
        wxBoxSizer* topSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);

        topSizer->Add(new wxButton(this, wxID_OK, "OK"),
            0,           // make horizontally unstretchable
            wxALL,       // make border all around (implicit top alignment)
            10);
        topSizer->Add(new wxButton(this, wxID_OK, "Button 1"), 0, wxALL, 10);
        topSizer->Add(new wxButton(this, wxID_OK, "Button 2"), 0, wxALL, 10);
}
```

However, when i create 3 button into DataViewPanel, then compile to show just one Button.

[image]

help me to show 3 button of panel in Gui Frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to associate your sizer with the panel, without `SetSizer(topSizer)` call the sizer is not used and hence all buttons remain superposed on each other in their default location instead of being correctly placed by it.